# "Manage Jenkins" sub-site cannot be accessed

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

With the help of `apt-get`, I installed Jenkins version 1.447.2+dfsg-3. I managed to put the `jenkins.war` under the directory `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`. When I connect to `http://localhost:8080/jenkins`, I get the dashboard homepage. I also access all sub-sites, however, the management part `.../jenkins/manage` fails. The browser needs endless time to connect to it.

I tried to google this problem, but I only get tips about how to "manage" Jenkins with the help of the view I cannot access. Why especially this sub-site? Is this a Jenkins bug or a problem with my Tomcat? Has anyone any idea how to fix this?

Let me know if you need more information via a comment.

Comment: I am running Jenkins ver 1.465 and jenkins.war is located under /usr/lib/jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Just as important is to know the Tomcat version, O/S version.

I would check logs and also you may be running into security issue with tomcat-users.xml.

The following is pretty concise and should help you:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat

Comment: Actually, I do not run Jenkins as tomcat webapp anymore. I installed the Jenkins package from the Wheezy repository. The version is 1.447.2+dfsg-3. It runs as a service on port 8080.